# Remove labels from JFreeChart Pie Chart

Tags: java, jfreechart, label, pie-chart

```
public static JFreeChart createChart(String title, List <Result> results){

    DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();

    Iterator<Result> itr = results.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Result result = itr.next();
        String itemName = result.getItemName();
        BigDecimal itemResult = result.getItemResult();
        pieDataset.setValue(itemName, itemResult);
        }

        JFreeChart chart = null;

        try {
            chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(title, pieDataset,true, false, false);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Threw a ParseException in createChart:, full message:",
                    e);
        }

    return chart;
    }
```

How do I turn the labels of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to set the label generator to null, using the `setLabelGenerator()` method on `PiePlot`.  You can get the plot from the chart and cast it to a `PiePlot`:

```
((PiePlot) chart.getPlot()).setLabelGenerator(null);
```